# How to convert following SQL query in criteria hibernate

Tags: hibernate

```
SELECT N.NATIONALITY_ID,N.CODE,N.NAME, N.BILINGUALNAME, N.ISACTIVE,
       to_char(N.MODIFIED_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as MODIFIED_DATE, U.LOGINID  
FROM DBD.TBL_NATIONALITY N,DBD.TBL_USER_INFO U 
WHERE N.MODIFIED_BY=U.USERID 
ORDER BY N.NAME,NATIONALITY_ID
```

Comment: In my project currently i passed this query by using native sql and i got the result but i want to know how to do by using criteria...
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(SqlStatement.Nationality_Retrieve);
   List<Object[]> records = query.list();

Comment: The internet is full of tutorials documents and examples. First try something, and ask the points you couldn't understand or if there's something not working. Nobody's going to convert a sql to hibernate criteria for you, but they will help you doing it.

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-criteria-examples/